# Custom calendar

Tags: datetime

I have a content type ("Event") with a "Date" field.
I'm using [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) and [Calendar](http://drupal.org/project/calendar) in order to have a calendar rendered in a block.
I want to change the behaviour of it, and focus only on the month and day, without taking care about the year. So, the dates 10/10/2010, 10/10/2011, 10/10/2012, 10/10/* should appear in the Calendar in every October 10th, no matter what year I'm seeing.

I thought about doing this using any of these two ways:

#### First one

I could do that using Date Repeat, but I see two inconvenients here:

- I have to specify a "To:" field in the Repetitions tab, and I just want it to repeat for **every** year.
- When viewing the details of some Event node, I will see a list with all repeated dates! (Yes, I could tweak this).

If I could solve the first issue, I think I will handle the second and I'll be done.

#### Second one

It would be great to have a calendar (in a month view, I only need it for a block view) where I can customize the link of each day, and make each day for every month clickable. For example, the day "October 10th, 2011" will be linked to /10102010, /10-10-2010 or whatever I specify.

Is there a way of doing this? I don't mind if I have to modify some modules or write some hooks in order to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I have had better luck customizing the FullCalendar module, it should be easier to accomplish the things you want with it: http://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar

There is even an IRC channel where you can get help: #drupal-fullcalendar